# Group Individuals in R by factor?

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset in R, in which I have 12 individuals that belong to 3 different groups. I imported my excel as a .csv, and tried to set up my "group" column as a factor for the pig ID numbers. However, when simply plotting the data or running things such as aov, it does not group them.. It still considers them individuals. How can I get R to recognize that the factors are groups? Here is the code I used

```
datum=import.csv(file.choose())
head(datum)
datum$Group=factor(datum$Pig)
plot(Protein~Group,data=datum)
resultsPRO=aov(Protein~Group,data=datum)
plot(resultsPRO)
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `Pig` be a unique identifier?  If so `factor(datum$Pig)` is going to have 12 levels.

Comment: I want to look at them as groups, but keep individual data points. I'm trying to get R to plot as groups rather than individuals.

Thats what I had in my original code, so does that mean i just need to flip 'group' and 'pig' around in the script?

Comment: what are the conditions that determine which pig is in which group?

Comment: By the group number. '1' has the 4 individuals in it, and so on. I have it in the excel clip i provided.

Comment: Sorry.  I missed that you linked to your data.  You need to use `datum$Group  = factor(data$Group)`

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!